# How to clear Terminal of command prompt after installing VSCode for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

as below:

Microsoft Windows [Version XXXXX]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Projects and Learning>"C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Projects and Learning/Project1.py"
**Welcome XXX!**

C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Projects and Learning>

Comment: just type "clear" in the terminal

Comment: @Sharry100 How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m understanding correctly you are just trying to clear what’s currently displayed in the terminal

`ctrl + l` clears the terminal
Or just type clear and press enter to clear the window

Comment: Hello there!
Nope, I just want to clear the junk of command prompt giving path everytime I run my code,.. Just a clean terminal with my output

Comment: Ok so per your initial post you just want “Welcome XXX”

Answer (score 0):

You can type clear or if you are looking for a fresh new terminal you can click on terminal up on the menu bar and select new terminal or use the Mac shortcut ^[shift] and `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit information such as the path and environment of the console, you could set it in the `launch.json` file of folder `.vscode`:

> `"console": "internalConsole",`

It will be set to only output the result to "`DEBUG CONSOLE`" when debugging a python script:

[image]

In addition, you could also set: `"console": "externalTerminal",` which will output the results of debugging python scripts to a separate cmd window:

[image]

Reference: [console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).